# How to set properties of a list from another different list in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists named RoleModel and RoleViewModel.

```
public class RoleVM
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string node { get; set; }
}

public partial class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ChildID { get; set; }
}
```

How can I assign the property of rolename (from rolemodel) to text(from rolevm)

```
public ActionResult getJsonTree()
{
    List<Role> _lstRole = _db.Roles.ToList();
    List<RoleVM> _lstViewRole = new List<RoleVM>();
    foreach(var _role in _lstRole)
    {
        if (_role.ChildID == null)
        {
            _lstViewRole.Add(_role);//Adds the role model to rolevm class
        }                
    }            
    return Json(_lstViewRole, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What is the KEY common in both list ?

Comment: You can't do this because `Role` and `RoleVM` are two different classes. `List<RoleVM>` will not accept `Role` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
List<RoleVM> _lstViewRole = _db.Roles.Where(x => x.Id == null).Select(x => new RoleVM() { text = x.RoleName }).ToList();
```

- select all items where `Id == null`
- create for each `Role` object a new `RoleVM` object and `Role.RoleName` goes to `RoleVM.text`